# How to save and load an image to a mysql database in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, image, swing

How do you save and load an image from a database and display it in Java? I can get the file location, but I am unsure as to how to save it as a blob in the database or display the image in a swing window. I am using a `PreparedStatement` to get information in and out of the database.

Comment: Are you sure storing an image in your MySQL database is a good idea? Images tend to be large, and SQL databases aren't a great way to store unstructured blobs of data.

Comment: It's only a small number of users on the system, so I think it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [*MySQL Java tutorial*](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqljava/) for examples under the sections *Writing images* and *Reading images*. In outline,

```
// writing
String sql = "INSERT INTO Images(Data) VALUES(?)";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(myFile);
pst.setBinaryStream(1, fin, (int) myFile.length());
pst.executeUpdate();

//reading
String query = "SELECT Data FROM Images LIMIT 1";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet result = pst.executeQuery();
result.next();
String fileName = "src/main/resources/tree.png";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
Blob blob = result.getBlob("Data");
int len = (int) blob.length();
byte[] buf = blob.getBytes(1, len);
fos.write(buf, 0, len);
```