# How can I load a image file as a blob in mysql database using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, image, blob, jogetworkflow

I have a admin panel in joget in which user data is added. In my registration form I have a image box which takes a user image. I have to show this image as a blob in MYSQL database. how can i show image values in blob format in mysql  and where I have to write code which convert image into blob.
please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save and load an image to a mysql database in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896945/how-to-save-and-load-an-image-to-a-mysql-database-in-java)

Comment: quite a common use case, simple google search should also help